# Simple CSS Transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to write a menu similar to the top animated logo on this site: [XOXCO](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/)

It looks like a simple CSS trick, but I am having some issues.  After looking at the source code and CSS file I have a couple of questions I am hoping someone can answer.

What makes the images return to their original position while still hovering (giving them that quick bounce effect)? And why isn't it repeating the transition over and over while hovered?  Is there more than CSS at work here, and I am just not seeing it?

Comment: it's done in javascript; look in main.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done in their `main.js`:

```
var delay = 500;
$('ul#animated_logo li').each(function() {
    (function(el) {
        setTimeout(function() { $(el).css('top','20px'); },delay);
    })(this);                           
    delay = delay + 100;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**it is just pure css3** animation-iteration-count  (**use css3 for performance and best practice**) you can read it at [developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count)
here i have animation-iteration-count =1

```
#e:hover { 
    animation: pulse 100ms ease-in-out 0s 1 alternate; 
} /* Works fine, pulses on hover */
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3PuT2/176/)

change it to 5 then you have this

```
#e:hover { 
    animation: pulse 100ms ease-in-out 0s 5 alternate; 
 } /* Works fine, pulses on hover */
```

[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/3PuT2/177/)

**FULL CODE**

HTML

```
<menu>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</menu>
```

CSS

```
menu li { 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin:10px;
    background-color: #000;
    float:left;
}
menu li:hover { 
    -webkit-animation: pulse 100ms ease-in-out 0s 5 alternate; 
    -moz-animation: pulse 100ms ease-in-out 0s 5 alternate; 
    animation: pulse 100ms ease-in-out 0s 5 alternate; 
} 



@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
        0%   { 
        -webkit-transform:translateY(-10px); 
        -moz-transform:translateY(-10px);
        transform:translateY(-10px);
    }
        100% { 
        -webkit-transform:translateY(0px);
        -moz-transform:translateY(0px);
        transform:translateY(0px);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect element of the page, select **network**, ensure that **record network log** is enabled, and then refresh the page you should be able to **filter for scripts** and find the javascript/jquery that they are using to animate their header images.. it is titled **main.js** and the code is as follows:

```
$(function() {
    // enable Aware.js, and add new flags to any sort of post-like content  
    $('.tile').aware();
    var delay = 500;
    $('ul#animated_logo li').each(function() {
        (function(el) {
            setTimeout(function() { $(el).css('top','20px'); },delay);
        })(this);                           
        delay = delay + 100;
    });
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('ul#animated_logo li').css('-webkit-transition-duration','0.1s');
        $('ul#animated_logo').on('mouseenter','li',function() {
        $(this).css('top','0px');
        (function(el) {
            setTimeout(function() { $(el).css('top','20px'); },100);
        })(this)
    });
    },delay);
});
```

They are applying the **main.js** script to the child element **li** of any unordered list with the id **animated_logo**.
Hope this helps.